# tensorflow-gpu stuck in epoch1 when using keras to proceed code

Tags: tensorflow, keras

While using the keras to proceed the code suddenly，the warining came out which are as follow：

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
2019 16:08:03.433226: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2060 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.89GiB
2019 16:08:03.435266: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019 16:08:05.728803: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019 16:08:05.730056: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0
2019 16:08:05.730321: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0: N
2019 16:08:05.730723: I c:\users\user\source\repos\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4644 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
```

My system information：

- win10
- cuda9.2
- cdunn7.2
- python3.65
- TensorFlow version :1.10.0
- GPU/CPU:RTX2060,i7 9750h
- memory:16g

But when I use tensorflow directly, without processing code by keras, there was no warning and competely successful.
Despite all this, I still prefer keras rather than directly using tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

For me this setup works with RTX2060 and i7 9750h:

win10,

CUDA 10.0,

cuDNN 7.4,

python 3.68,

tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1

References: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Finally, I install the version which you show me, it already could run the code now, thanks a lot